# Can we call python script from jquery (While working with django)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

can we call python script from jquery(while working with django framework). if yes then how we can do that.Please explain step by step (Since i am new to django and jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about an ajax call to get some response data or a rendered string. If that's the case:

For a get request,

```
$.get("url/end/point",function(json_response){ ...do some thing with the response...});
```

For a get request,

```
$.post("url/end/point",function(json_response){ ...do some thing with the response...});
```

Like rendering a general get or post view, you need to add the url to the urls.py either in the app or the project (However you like.)

In the view, you need to add,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
         ....process the request....
         return JsonResponse(data) (or) HttpResponse(data)
```